# Highstocks period scroll not working with jQuery tabs in IE

Tags: jquery-tabs, highcharts

I am using highstocks to chart a graph in a page within a tab(jQuery tabs) and in the Internet Explorer the period scroll bar(the one right below the graph where you can change the time span being charted) doesn't work.

Graph example working well: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hnkbh/

Same graph, but using jQuery tabs:
http://jsfiddle.net/zFRYJ/29/

The strange thing is, in Chrome and Firefox it has no problem at all. 
Did anyone encounter with a similar problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

commenting out the following line in the jQuery UI theme:

```
.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }
```

Works! http://jsfiddle.net/zFRYJ/40/

Via:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/330